# How to set ${var_name}

Tags: php

We are developing a mail system, and we would like to allow user to add custom greeting while creating message.. for example, check following...

we will set this variable(var_name) in php.

```
Hello ${var_name},
This is test message.
```

we are not using any framework.

Comment: Are you sure that's not some obscure template system within PHP ... or another language altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)?

```
$text = str_replace('${var_name}', $var_name, $text);
```

Comment: @seoppc str_replace even can take arrays as arguments, so you can fill all your variables at once.

Comment: i am getting a problem, its only replacing ${varname} with 1st entry of db inside of foreach loop. check following code...

foreach($users as $user) {
$content = str_replace('$name', $user['name'], $content);
$msg = '<div class="message">'.$content.'</div>';

Answer (score 1):

I'd use PHP as the templating language it is:

```
Hello <?php echo $name; ?>,
This is a test message.
```

Then you can replace them like this:

```
function render($template, $vars = array()) {
    extract($vars, EXTR_SKIP);
    ob_start();
    include $template;
    return ob_get_clean();
}

echo render('email.tmpl', array('name' => 'Foo'));
```

Comment: it's not HTML page template but custom email template **created by users**

Comment: @Col Now that you mention it... That wasn't all that clear to me.

Answer (score -1):

One way is to do the following:

Create a separate .php file for each email template, like so:

```
//email_text.php
Hello <?php echo $name ?>, <br/>
How are you doing?<br/>
Your truly,<br/>
<?php echo $author ?>
```

In the page which is sending the emails, you do something like this -

```
$name = 'Kevin';
$author = 'Freddy';  
ob_start();
include('email_text.php');
$output = ob_get_clean();
//$output now contains your email message with $name and $author substituted
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$var_name = 'Powtac';

// ...

$template = "Hello ${var_name},
This is test message.";

echo $template;
```